# how to use Keras TimeDistributed on back-end conv2d ( not layer Conv2D)

Tags: python-3.x, keras

i need to send a custom kernel to the conv2d while using TimeDistributed in the same time. timeDistributed is using layer only, but if i used Conv2D ( the layer) i will not be able to set my custom Kernel.

note: i am building my custom Layer that overwrite the Conv2D, on which i have to set the self.Kernal on the build method and re-use it when calling the conv2D.

is there any way to set the Kernel on Conv2D layer by the one i initialized on the build method, while using the wrraper "TimeDistributed"

```py
class myCustomLayer(Conv2D):

    def build(self, input_shape):        

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=kernel_shape,
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      name='img_kernel',
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
        # Mask kernel
        self.kernel_mask = K.ones(shape=self.kernel_size + (self.input_dim, self.filters))

        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.filters,),
                                        initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                        name='bias',
                                        regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                        constraint=self.bias_constraint)
        else:
            self.bias = None
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):


        img_output = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(self.filters,
            self.kernel_size , 
            strides=self.strides,
            padding=self.padding,
            data_format=self.data_format,
            dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate,
            activation=self.activation,
            use_bias = True,
            kernel_initializer=self.kernel_initializer,            
            bias_initializer=self.bias_initializer,
            kernel_regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
            bias_regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
            bias_constraint=self.bias_constraint,
            kernel_constraint=self.kernel_constraint

        ))(inputs[0])


        mask_output = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(self.filters,
            self.kernel_size, 
            strides=self.strides,
            padding=self.padding,            
            data_format=self.data_format,
            dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate,
            use_bias = False,
            kernel_initializer='Ones',
            activation=None
        ))(inputs[1])

        return [img_output, mask_output]
```

Comment: How exactly are you setting the kernel of Conv2D?

Comment: Then why not first write your custom layer which contains `conv2d` operations.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro actually this is my question, in conv2d operation we can, but in Conv2D layer i don't know

Comment: @pitfall if i write one custom layer that use the conv2d, then when i implementing the main custom one, in which i will use the timedistributed wrapper, i will have the same dead lock, if i didn't define weights on build method, i will not be able to set this new weights (kernel) while invoicing the first custom layer inside timeDistributed wrapper.

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried, to me it sounds like a misunderstanding, specially the parts when you say you can't do something.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro code added , please have a look

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro did you look to the code attached ? thanks in davance